# Laptop cannot turn on Wifi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have an Acer Aspire Timeline X, I reinstalled Windows a couple of days ago. I've used my ethernet cable for the past couple of days and now want to use the WiFi, however when I unplug my ethernet cable I'm not able to connect to WiFi because it's turned off. When I push the keys to turn it on (Fn+F3) the old pop up that I had doesn't show up. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have necessary drivers. Find driver downloads for your model on Acer's website and download Wi-Fi drivers. You may also need some utility to enable hotkey support (you may identify it by looking up descriptions for something related to hotkeys, keyboard shortcuts, ACPI or extended power management).

If you can't find that utility, but have Wi-Fi drivers properly installed you'll be able to enable it in Mobility Center, you can access it quickly by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or by right-clicking battery in the notification area.

Comment: Windows Mobility Center has "Turn Wireless On", however it's blacked out.

I've tried to download the drivers but they failed to install.

Comment: Have you installed the Wi-Fi driver I've mentioned? Start with that :)